# Transform pandas panel into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a **`pandas.Panel`**, and I want to create a **`pandas.DataFrame`** with the column headers coming from one column, the data from another column, and the number of rows is the number of items in the panel.

If diagrams will help describe what I'm looking for...

My panel looks somewhat like the following:

```
      +---+---------+------------+------+
    +---+---------+------------+------+ |
  +---+---------+------------+------+ |-+
+---+---------+------------+------+ |-+ |
|   | context | iterations | time |-+ |-+
+---+---------+------------+------+ |-+ |
| 0 | foo     |          1 |   21 |-+ |-+
+---+---------+------------+------+ |-+ |
| 1 | bar     |          2 |   37 |-+ |-+
+---+---------+------------+------+ |-+
| 2 | baz     |          1 |   53 |-+
+---+---------+------------+------+
```

I would like to transform the panel into a dataframe:

- The dataframe column headers are the **"context" column**
- The dataframe values are the **"time" column**
- The number of rows in the dataframe is the **number of items in the panel**

The result would look something like this:

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|   | foo | bar | baz |
+---+-----+-----+-----+
| 0 |  21 |  37 |  53 |
+---+-----+-----+-----+
| 1 |  36 |  42 |  76 |
+---+-----+-----+-----+
| 2 |  24 |  56 |  83 |
+---+-----+-----+-----+
| 3 |  17 |  32 |  45 |
+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: By panel do you mean the pandas data structure (i.e. pd.Panel)? Or a collection of DataFrames? If it is a collection of DataFrames, how do you store them? In a list?

Comment: @ayhan a pandas panel, I'll clarify on the question

Comment: I am not sure about the structure of your panel but something like  `pn.minor_xs('time').T` should work.

Comment: You should be able to convert from panel to multi-index dataframe with `to_frame()`:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#conversion-to-dataframe  Can't test as you didn't provide sample data.  More generally if you read the other things at that link you'll find that panel is deprecated in favor of either multi-indexed dataframes or xarrays.

Comment: PlusOne4AsciiDiagram

Comment: BTW it is a good idea to start forgetting pandas.Panel() as it is now deprecated. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#deprecate-panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
*`pd.concat`*

```
pd.concat({i: d.set_index('context').time for i, d in pn.iteritems()}).unstack()

context  foo  bar  baz
0         21   37   53
1         36   42   76
2         24   56   83
3         17   32   45
```

---

**Option 2**
*`pd.DataFrame`*

```
pd.DataFrame([d.set_index('context').time for i, d in pn.iteritems()], pn.items)

context  foo  bar  baz
0         21   37   53
1         36   42   76
2         24   56   83
3         17   32   45
```